# Basic Question on Finding Poles and Zeros

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-theory

What are the zeros and poles of the following? They seem different based on how algebraic rearrangement is done:

$$
  X(z) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}\right)^5}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}\right)}
         = \frac{1}{(2z)^5-(2z)^4}
$$

Clearly \$\frac{1}{2}\$ is a pole based on either rearrangement. Is zero a pole as well?

Is there a general rule of thumb for how to do algebraic rearrangment to measure zeros and poles?

Comment: Typically you want to factor out all the terms, as you've done. You'd be able to continue by factoring out \$ z^4\$ in the denominator. From there, it will be clear that zero is a pole. You'll want to have the z left in parentheses with no coefficient; rising that will make the other pile clear. Check out this high quality resource: http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write the equation in positive powers of z; factorise, if required, and simplify; identify the poles and zeroes by inspection.

You've already gone most of the way, the final step is:

\$X(z)=\dfrac{1}{(2z)^4(2z-1)}=\dfrac{1}{32z^4(z-0.5)}\$

Which gives four poles at \$z=0\$ and a pole at \$z=0.5\$.

There are no finite zeroes.

The way the algebra is 'done' is irrelevant, there is only one correct outcome! But some forms of an equation may make it easier to identify the features you're looking for.